# Logo on west side on the same page

Tags: tikz-styles, includegraphics

When I am trying to insert logo or image picture is going to be post in frist page how I can force the picture to be stay on that postion only?

```
\documentclass[5p,times,authoryear]{elsarticle}
\addtobeamertemplate{}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node 
{\includegraphics[height=0.8cm]{logodimec.PNG}};
\end{tikzpicture}}
```

Comment: For Review Problem You can https://www.overleaf.com/1226323742qfpcpbbrsbcj
 check it here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw your overleaf document. It seems like what you like to do is to put a logo image above your title. In this case,

1. add `\usepackage{tikz}` in your preamble.
2. modify your title like this

```
\title{CAVIDAD RECTANGULAR DE AIRE CON 4 TEMPERATURAS IMPUESTAS
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\node[yshift=1cm,above left]{%
\includegraphics[width=3.5cm]{logofcfm.png}\hspace*{10cm}~%
\includegraphics[width=3.5cm]{logodimec.PNG}
};
\end{tikzpicture}}
```

This creates a box whose below right point is 1cm above the end of the word IMPUESTAS.

3. **Compile TWICE** so that remember picture & overlay options work

[image: result]

Comment: @Community I am not familiar with elsartile.cls and I could not managed to work with current page node option of tikz. My solution above is unstable when the title length changes. If somebody can post a working example with current page node, it would be better.

Comment: One Last Query on the first-page number is not in center! How I can fix this issue?

Comment: @Sagarkumar Zalavadiya In your document there was  `\def\@oddfoot{\centerline{\thepage}}%`. Change this to `\def\@oddfoot{\hfill{\thepage}\hfill}%`.